# Not able to include LibOPT library in C project in windows visual studio code

Tags: dynamic-library

I am trying to include [LibOPT](https://github.com/jppbsi/LibOPT) library to C project but the lib folder contains only the .gitignore file?

So on including lib folder in linker its not working?
don't know what to do??